# Application class does it run on UI thread or?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Sorry for being a newbie but i created a method in Application class in java, is it safe to run a method with complex to medium algorithm? is it going to be a hiccup in the UI's?

Comment: Funny that I've never thought about it

Comment: I almost sure that it runs in UI thread, but interesting how initialization is going

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> complex to medium algorithm

if it is complex, you should run it in an asynchronous way, using a `Thread`, an `AsyncTask`, an `IntentService` or whatever suits you better, but don't run it directly on the a subclass of `Application`/`Activity`/`Fragment`/`Service` or whatever runs on the UI Thread. It will slow down the start up of you application otherwise.

Comment: yes, most of my functions are somewhat to medium to complex , creates lag in my ui's when im not doing any thread. thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 10):

From [Processes and Threads | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) (emphasis mine):

> When an application component starts and the application does not have
>   any other components running, the Android system starts a new Linux
>   process for the application with a single thread of execution. **By
>   default, all components of the same application run in the same
>   process and thread (called the "main" thread).** If an application
>   component starts and there already exists a process for that
>   application (because another component from the application exists),
>   then the component is started within that process and uses the same
>   thread of execution. However, you can arrange for different components
>   in your application to run in separate processes, and you can create
>   additional threads for any process.

And:

> The system does not create a separate thread for each instance of a
>   component. **All components that run in the same process are
>   instantiated in the UI thread, and system calls to each component are
>   dispatched from that thread.** Consequently, methods that respond to
>   system callbacks (such as onKeyDown() to report user actions or a
>   lifecycle callback method) always run in the UI thread of the process.

So yes, methods like `onCreate` in your `Application` class will be called on the main (UI) thread.

There are only a few classes that do start asynchronously, like the [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) for example.

Answer (score 4):

Yes all application components from activity to broadcast receivers run on ui thread,only when you have to do some long fetching task or background execution or a network fetch do it in a separate thread using asynctask or intent service,so that it does nor slag down your ui screen.

Comment: I would (my own understanding) personally choose runnables as of now, cause there was some blog that its more faster than asynctask. thank you for your answer